# c++ cross platform way to define 64bit unsigned integer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc

Right now I'm working on a project that extensively uses 64bit unsigned integers in many parts of the code. So far we have only been compiling with gcc 4.6 but we are now porting some code to windows. It's crucial that these unsigned ints are 64bits wide. It has been suggested that we could use long long but it's not good if long long happens to be bigger than 64bits, we actually want to have a guarantee that it will be 64 bits and writing something like `static_assert(sizeof(long long) == 8)` seems to be a bit of a code smell.

What is the best way to define something like uint64 that will compile across both gcc and msvc without needing to have different code syntax used everywhere?

Comment: would an ifdef and a typedef together do the trick?

Comment: @DavidFeurle, it might be sufficient, the purpose of asking this question was to get a feel for what the best practices are here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What about including `cstdint` and using `std::uint64_t`?

Comment: That's only in c++11. Before that most compilers had an intrinsic to do the job.

Comment: @kukyakya, I'm doing that on gcc at the moment, but I don't know if there's a static assert on MSVC as I have very little experience developing with that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use boost:

> The typedef int#_t, with # replaced by the width, designates a signed
>   integer type of exactly # bits; for example int8_t denotes an 8-bit
>   signed integer type. Similarly, the typedef uint#_t designates an
>   unsigned integer type of exactly # bits.

See: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/cstdint.html

Especially this header: 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/cstdint.hpp

Comment: Interesting suggestion, since we use boost a lot this might do this trick if `cstdint` isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do:

```
#ifndef u64
#ifdef WIN32
typedef unsigned __int64   u64;
#else // !WIN32
typedef unsigned long long u64;
#endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can use `__int64`, `unsigned __int64`, or typedefs: `UINT64`, `INT64` etc.

Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa383751%28VS.85%29.aspx)

But yes, if code portability is concern, use standard typedefs, as suggested by others.